# How to calculate the retention rates of my customers?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to calculate the retention rates of my users, and I am having difficulties to get what I need. What I want to do is for any given date be able to calculate all the new registered users and see how many come back the following days, weeks, months, etc.

I have therefore different retention metrics which I'm calling D1 (one day retention rate), D7 (one week retention rate) and this up to D365 (so one year retention rate).

Below is a simplified example of my table structure:

| loginDate | userId | installDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 1 | 01/01/2023 |
| 01/01/2023 | 2 | 01/01/2023 |
| 01/01/2023 | 3 | 01/01/2023 |
| 02/01/2023 | 1 | 01/01/2023 |
| 02/01/2023 | 4 | 02/01/2023 |
| 03/01/2023 | 4 | 02/01/2023 |
| 08/01/2023 | 1 | 01/01/2023 |

And here is a simplified example of the result that my query should return:

| Date | D1 | D7 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01/2023 | 33% | NULL |
| 03/01/2023 | 100% | NULL |
| 08/01/2023 | NULL | 33% |

Finally, here is my current query:

```
  SELECT
       loginDate AS Date,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) = 1 THEN 1 END) / count(*) AS D1,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) = 7 THEN 1 END) / count(*) AS D7
  FROM logins
  GROUP BY loginDate
```

While I believe the sum part is correct, dividing by count(*) looks wrong. I've been trying to divide by count(distinct userId) but no luck as well. Overall, I'm not too sure on how to take into account each relevant day for my calculations. For instance, if we take the D1 metric, I'm struggling to find out how to divide the users who came back on T+1 by the total users who created their account on T.

Could anyone help please?

**EDIT:**

Replying to @FanoFN.
Please find below the code I used based on yours:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS
(SELECT loginDate,
       DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) Intervals,
       COUNT(loginDate=installDate) userCount
  FROM logins
GROUP BY Intervals, loginDate),
 cte2 AS (
  SELECT loginDate,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Intervals=0 THEN userCount ELSE 0 END) totalInstalledUser,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Intervals=1 THEN userCount ELSE 0 END) D1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Intervals=7 THEN userCount ELSE 0 END) D7
FROM cte1
GROUP BY loginDate)
SELECT loginDate,
       (D1/totalInstalledUser)*100 D1Percentage,
       (D7/totalInstalledUser)*100 D7Percentage
   FROM cte2
   GROUP BY loginDate
```

Comment: I think you should be displaying and grouping by `installdate`, not `logindate`.

Comment: How you get these percentages ??

Comment: I think you should group by day intervals and not by `installDate` nor `loginDate`.. because not all `userId` have the same `installDate` therefore if you group by dates, your `SUM(CASE..` function can detect it as 1 day interval but it will be grouped separately.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @SelVazi: as an example, on the 1st of January, I have userId 1, 2 and 3 who created an account and logged in. The following day, only userId 1 came back, so the day one retention rate for that day is 33%. I hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `WITH`, `COUNT OVER PARTITION` As follows :

`cte` and `cte2` is to get number of loggings per day.

`cte3` is to get the Amount of users and If the range is D1 or D7.

`cte4` to get the percentages.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
  count(case when loginDate=installDate then 1 end) 
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY installDate ORDER BY loginDate
    ) AS Count_Logins
  FROM logins
  
),
cte2 AS (
  select cte.*, count(1) OVER (PARTITION BY loginDate, installDate order by loginDate) as today_logs
  from cte
), 
cte3 AS (
   select loginDate, installDate,
   MAX(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) = 1 THEN 1 END)  AS D1,
   MAX(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) = 7 THEN 1 END)  AS D7,
   MAX(today_logs)/MAX(Count_Logins) AS Amount
   from cte2
   WHERE DATEDIFF(loginDate, installDate) > 0
   GROUP BY loginDate, installDate 
),
cte4 AS (
  select loginDate, D1*Amount*100 AS D1, D7*Amount*100 AS D7
  from cte3
)
select *
from cte4;
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gR9Lb2GfHojb5YWXynQ5VX/0)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, we're very close. Nevertheless, in the original database, the loginDate field is of datetime data type and sometimes a user would login more than once in a day, thus inflating the Count_Logins value. We therefore need to make sure each userId is being counted only once. What is the easiest way to proceed? Amending your first case statement (line 3 of your code) with something like 'count(case when loginDate=installDate and distinct userId then 1 end)' obviously doesn't work, but reflects the idea of what I'm looking for. Do you have any easy fix for that?

Comment: Something like this ? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gR9Lb2GfHojb5YWXynQ5VX/1

Comment: Yes, that led to the expected resuts, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your expected result as the result you're getting with your current query and a couple of crucial information that you missed out in your question is that the `loginDate` is in fact `DATETIME` datatype and *" sometimes a user would login more than once in a day...... We therefore need to make sure each `userId` is being counted only once"*. I've made another attempt here for you to test:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT installDate,
         SUM(DATE(loginDate)=installDate) InstalledCount
  FROM logins 
  GROUP BY installDate
  ),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT DATE(l.loginDate) LgnDt,
       DATEDIFF(l.loginDate, l.installDate) Intervals,
       COUNT(DISTINCT userId) TotalLogin,
       cte1.InstalledCount
FROM logins l
JOIN cte1
 ON l.installDate=cte1.installDate
WHERE DATE(l.loginDate) != l.installDate
GROUP BY LgnDt, Intervals, cte1.InstalledCount)
SELECT LgnDt,
       CASE WHEN Intervals=1 THEN (TotalLogin/InstalledCount)*100 ELSE 0 END AS D1,
       CASE WHEN Intervals=7 THEN (TotalLogin/InstalledCount)*100 ELSE 0 END AS D7
FROM cte2
```

[With a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BYiJ4fw_)

The changes I made are:

1. Using `DATE()` function to extract date from `loginDate` column wherever necessary.
2. Adding `DISTINCT` in `COUNT(DISTINCT userId) TotalLogin,` to make sure that a `userId` is only counted once a day regardless how many times they login.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I believe we are nearly there. I had to make a few amendments to your code since what I want is to see the retention for each day, rather than the aggregated numbers. I therefore added the loginDate in the group by. 
But the numbers were not exactly matching what I was expecting. It appears that my loginDate is of datetime data type and sometimes the same user would login more than once in a day, thus inflating the userCount value. Would there be an easy way to amend the 'COUNT(loginDate=installDate)' line so it only uses distinct userId?

Comment: I'm interested to know more about what you're trying to get here. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75414348/edit) and show me - in the current suggestion I gave you - on what did you add and want it to look like?

Comment: The result of your exmple returned aggregated metrics. What I want is to have these same metrics for each day instead, so I can see the retention rates evolution over time (see my second table for an example of how I would like the final results to be displayed). I've edited my initial question and added as requested the changes I made to your code. I hope it makes more sense.

Comment: @curiousIT , I have posted an updated answer.